# default value for 'on' on a left join if it returns a null

Tags: mysql

this is my current query which is not working

assume `@value` is dynamic

```
SELECT * FROM item as items 
left join item_detail as details on items.id = details.item_id 
and (details.language_id = @value or details.language_id = '1')
```

what I'm trying to do is, when there is no `@value` for `details.language_id` or it returns null, it should left join with a value `1`

***update**

when `@value = 2`, this should be the possible result of the query

```
+------+------------------+-------------+
| item_name | language_id | description |
|-----------+-------------+-------------+
|  Umbrella |      2      |  とても良い   |
|  Belt     |      1      | very sturdy |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

not

```
+------+------------------+-------------+
| item_name | language_id | description |
|-----------+-------------+-------------+
|  Umbrella |      2      |  とても良い    |
|  Belt     |    null     |     null    |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

this means, `belt` has no `item_detail` with `language_id = 2`, but has `language_id = 1` which is the default

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE` to default to your desired value, like so:

```
SELECT 
items.item_name, 
coalesce
(item_id,  
 (select item_id from item_detail d
  inner join item i on d.item_id = i.id
  where language_id = 1 limit 1)
) item_id,
coalesce
(description, 
 (select item_id from item_detail d
  inner join item i on d.item_id = i.id
  where language_id = 1 limit 1)
) description 
FROM item as items
left join item_detail as details on items.id = details.item_id 
and (details.language_id = @Value)
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will return the fields as NULL where a match cannot be found. Therefore, we need to default the fields in question to the required value. We do this by querying an `INNER JOIN` of the 2 tables with the `language_id` defaulted to 1, since this value is guaranteed to exist for every item.

Comment: i tried your suggestion with `coalesce('2','1')` it returns me with null column values for details with no `language_id = 2`

Comment: Wouldn't that happen if `@value` was equal to '2' anyway? Could be I misunderstood your intention. What do you want to return if there are no records available with `language_id` = '2'?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out your problem

Could you please try below SQL and let me know if it works for you

```
SELECT * FROM item AS items 
LEFT JOIN item_detail AS details 
ON items.id = details.item_id 
WHERE  (details.language_id = COALESCE((SELECT language_id FROM item_detail WHERE language_id= @VALUE ),'1')
```

Comment: (SELECT language_id FROM item WHERE language_id= @VALUE ) is invalid because language_id is in item_detail